# JSF2 EL html output

Tags: jsf

#### Background

I have an existing web application that relies on JSF2. In most pages, there are expressions that output text from various property files. Some properties might contain html. However, JSF expressions escape html into plain text. The solution I found was to use <h:outputText> with escape set to false. Using this would be cumbersome due to amount of expressions that would need to be wrapped.

#### Question

My question is, is there a way to configure all expressions to not escape html?

Comment: Yes, I realize this. However the html will not be set by the user but a third party who has access to the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create my own composite component wich can be called In xhtml with

`<myComponents:outputText value="<STRONG>the html taged value</STRONG>">`

Simply add this custom component in a new xhtml file in the defaut jsf folder `src/webapp/components`.

Like :

#### src/webapp/components/myComponents/outputText.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" escape="false"/>
    </cc:implementation>

</ui:composition>
```

Don't forget to add the folowwing namespace in your xhtml pages where the components are used `xmlns:field="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/myComponents` in the `ui:composition` tag

Hope this helps...

Comment: I understand. However, this will not work for me since i can't go through every page and replace #{expression} with <myComponent:out>. If that were the case then I would just use <h:outputText>. Thank you though.